# refresh TTThumbsViewController on a buttonClick in Three20

Tags: iphone, three20

I have this view having Thumbnails and certain set of buttons.

I am using TTThumbsViewController to render this view and MockDataSource (provided in TTCatalog) to store images.

my datasource is dynamic and changes everytime in some period of time.

Now what I want to do is refresh(reload) the  thumbnails after clicking a button on the same Thumbnails screen is there any way to achieve this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TTTHumbsViewController inherits from TTTableViewController which inherits from TTModelViewController.

If your dataSource is created using the createModel function, you can have the button call invalidateModel to regenerate the thumbnails.

Alternatively, you could just move your dataSource creation to a function and re-run that and do a reload on the view.