# Three20 - Attempt to Refresh TTThumbsViewController stays stuck on "Loading..."

Tags: iphone, three20

I am using a `TTThumbsViewController` to display a gallery. Users can upload photos to a server and when the upload is complete I post a notification which I receive further up the navigation stack at the `TTThumbViewController` where I want to reload the gallery so that when the user navigates back the gallery includes their newly added photo.

I call the following in my `TTThumbsViewController` subclass when I receive the notification:

```
[self invalidateModel];
[self reload];
```

This results in a message of "Loading" with a spinner but it stays stuck there. Hoping someone can nudge me in the right direction. Thank you!

Other things I've tried:

```
[self invalidateModel];
```

or

```
[self invalidateModel];
[self reload];
[self updateView];
```

or

```
[self invalidateModel];
[self reloadIfNeeded];
```

I've reviewed this SO question and tried the approach:

[refresh TTThumbsViewController on a buttonClick in Three20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973239/refresh-ttthumbsviewcontroller-on-a-buttonclick-in-three20)

Comment: I hacked around this by simply reinitializing my datasource and setting it as the photosource again. Would still know the proper way to do this as I'm guessing it's not reiniting :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the Following code

## creating model

```
- (void)createModel {


    [self setPhotoSourceToView];

}
```

## Setting the NSNotification

```
NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(setPhotoSourceToView) name:NOTIF_UPDATES object:nil];
```

## setPhotoSourceToView Function

```
- (void)setPhotoSourceToView {
       if (!doPhotoSource) {
                //call to datasource
                XXXPhotoSource=[[XXXThumbnailPhotoSource alloc]initWithURL:urlForDo ];

                }
            self.photoSource = XXXPhotoSource;

        }
}
```

This works fine

Answer (score 0):

I just did this and it worked fine for me.

`[self reload];`